# Get the records matching the combination of column values from a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have a temp table with 4 columns

question_tbl:

## TempTable -- combination to lookup

```
id      | Code1    | Code2       | code3
--------+----------+-------------+---------
111       | AA       | A1          | X
222       | BB       | B1          | Y
333       | CC       | C1          | Z
444       | DD       | D1          | ZZ

Code1 and Code2 are columns in tableA , Code3 is in table3
Table A has Records
DeptID      | Code1    | Code2       | 
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A           | AA       | A1          | 
B           | BC       | B1          | 
C           | CC       | C1          | 
D           | DC       | D1          | 
E           | DD       | D1          | 
Table B has Records
DeptID      | Code1     
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A           | X
B           | XX       
C           | Z       
D           | YY       
E           | Z Z      

I have to use the temptable to lookup on both table A and B.
If I find the 3 combinations matching using both tables, then I append Id 
value from Temp to DeptId in TableB
So my final result should be

DeptID      | Code1     
--------+----------+-------------+---------
A111           | X
C333           | Z       
E444           | ZZ
```

The query that I am using currently is as below. It is working fine. But gives 
   me a performance issue because number of records in table A and B are more 
   than  20000

```
SELECT B.DeptID + T.ID
FROM TableA                                 A
INNER JOIN #TMP                             T 
    ON T.Code3  = A.Code3
INNER JOIN TableB                           B
    ON B.Code1  = T.Code1  AND B.Code2 =  T.Code2

is there any other alternative way to lookup the combinations on the table? 
Please suggest. Thanks for the help!
```

Comment: If the query works but is slow, you'll likely need to look into what indexes are available. Can you let us know what you have already?

Comment: The indexes are all created in the physical tables. TableA has clustered Index on Id, Code1 and code 2. Table B has clustered index on id and code2.  I have created a non clustered index on temptable on the three columns code1, code2, and code3

Comment: Also, wanted to know if there is an alternate way of achieving this. As the join with temp table is doing a cross join resulting in slow performance.

Comment: I think your description of your tables and fields is messed up.  I know you are probably trying to obfuscate the code, but you need to make sure everything lines up when you do that.  Can you also post the actual index definitions as well?

Comment: At a minimum, I think you need a non-clustered index on TableA for Code3.  You're joining on TableA using Code3